# CQRS/EventStore - Modelling and storing hierarchical tree

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I was wondering if anyone has tackled the issue of using CQRS and Event-Sourcing (Event-Store) with hierarchical trees?

We hope to have 10s of 1000s of nodes and childs in the tree and I am concerned whether CQRS with Event sourcing is not a good match for this problem. I have yet to look at snap shots which could be used on the event-store side.

Also from a DDD perspective, would I model it as a composite design pattern in my model or should it be more reflective of how the data is stored in my read model (i.e. SQL server in this case).

Comment: What invariants/consistency rules exist between these nodes? What does a node represent? Do you work in the domain of binary trees?

Comment: The best way to describe it is a itunes type of tree structure where we allow users to upload videos. There could be many sub folders (artist name/album etc). Definately not in the domain of binary trees. We can allow users to delete folders (which would delete the videos), move videos between folders, delete videos and copy videos from one folder to another.

Comment: I need to just go down the tree and lazy load each sub tree and then if the user picks a sub tree, then lazy load its children. I cannot see any other requirements apart from anything other than you can do with for example a windows Explorer tree like structure.

Comment: Seems very crud-like, solved many times (off the shelf components), in the realm of the UI ... don't see the correlation to DDD. What value are you hoping to get out of using eventsourcing/cqrs in this case? Why not simple model nodes as individual (data) entities and be done with it? Use a data model, not a domain model, IMO.

Comment: @YvesReynhout: Thank you for the information. After another meeting with the Business Analyst we need permission checking which can become a bit complex. In addition this is my first CQRS/event sourcing project which contains other DDD models so I was thinking that this problem was just an extension of the domain.

Comment: @YvesReynhout: You mentioned "simple model nodes", can you please elaborate?

Comment: More information on permissions: The permission could be on a parent folder and all sub folders would have the same permission, so I need to have some way of traversing up the tree. Do I still need a domain model?

Comment: For one, you need to be able to propagate those permissions to descendant nodes. You could use messaging or bulk updates for that (SQL is very good at set-based operations). If I say "simple node model", I don't mean you can't use OO. Model your node such that it encapsulates its direct children (or references identifiers) and the permissionset that is applicable. Code the permission assertions inside the node behaviors. Would this make it a domain model? Could be, but I doubt the rules are everchanging :-). As such, it's not, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to agree with the comments, that there really isn't an advantage to CQRS for your application.  It's a poor fit.

To answer your original question for someone else's benefit, I am building an application for Provisioning that uses CQRS & EventSourcing that has what are basically hierarchical trees.  I am using a graphing database [ Neo4J ] to handle the hierarchy...  [ Lots of groups at 6 - 8 different levels ].

The Domain reflects the relationships bottom up, while Neo4J will handle both direction.  That way the eventStore can update very quickly, and for those handlers which need to traverse the tree/graph [ in order to create lists of accessible nodes ], they can use the Graphing Database for that.

CQRS is actually a pretty good fit for this application, and I was actually fairly surprised that there was no push back at all to my approach with this.  Everyone seemed to agree that this was a much better alternative to a more traditional CRUD approach.

The system I am replacing stores these relationships in SQL, and that's where are having HUGE performance issues!   This should be dramatically better.

Comment: Daniel, what do your events look like?

Comment: THere are quite a few of them, and they are domain specific..   Stuff like "StudentAdded", or "StudentEnrolled", or "UserChangedSchools".  Not sure specifically what you are looking for.